# Como usar o Database Diagrams no Visual Studio 2015

Tags: c#, banco-de-dados, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, diagrama

Estou fazendo os exercícios do livro: "Use a Cabeça C#", e um dos exercícios foi pedido para criar um Database diagrams. Porém não tem essa opção no Microsoft Visual Studio 2015.

Página do livro:
[image: Página do livro Use a Cabeça C#]

Assim que está meu Visual Studio:

[image: Meu Visual Studio]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Não existe mais](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/y5a4ezk9(v=vs.140)?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397). Dá para instalar o SQL Server Management Studio que tem isso, mas não é a mesma coisa.

Esse livro é muito antigo. Ou precisa aprender com algo mais novo ou precisa fazer adaptações no seu estudo, o que não é uma má ideia, porque se for só seguir direitinho o que diz um livro passo por passo, não está aprendendo de verdade, está apenas seguindo um programa de adestramento.

Comment: Entendi. Mas o que ficou no lugar dele então? E além do SQL Server Management, tem mais alguma coisa que possa ser usado?

Comment: Pra produzir diagramas de bancos de dados tem um monte de software por aí, em geral compatíveis com os principais DBs do mercado.

Answer (score 0):

Como @Maniero mencionou, não existe mais. Uma alternativa que gosto muito é o [DBeaver](https://dbeaver.io/). Ele é bem completo, tem suporte a MySQL, PostgreSQL, SQLite, Oracle, DB2, SQL Server, Sybase, MS Access, Teradata, Firebird, Apache Hive, Phoenix, Presto, etc. Tem suporte ao Linux, Mac e Windows. Você também consegue criar diagramas através dele.

Aqui vai um [tutorial](https://king.host/wiki/artigo/acessar-um-banco-sql-server-pelo-dbeaver/) de como acessar o SQL Server no DBeaver